# 3D plot from lm model with a nonlinear parameter

Tags: validation, r, data-visualization

I am trying to plot a 3Dplot of a linear regression with two variables.

My linear model:

```
ls = lm(mpg ~ disp + qsec, data = mtcars)
```

The minimum and maximum values to predict:

```
mmd = min(mtcars$disp):max(mtcars$disp)
mmq = min(mtcars$qsec):max(mtcars$qsec)
```

The linear function:

```
flm = function(x1, x2) ( (ls$coefficients[1]) + (ls$coefficients[2] * x1) + (ls$coefficients[3] * x2))
```

The outer matrix:

```
t = outer(X = mmd, Y = mmq, FUN = flm)
```

The plot:

```
persp3D(z = t, ticktype = "detailed")
```

[image]

Now I would like to control for the non-linearity of the `qsec` parameter.

Is this the right way to do it?

```
ls = lm(mpg ~ disp + poly(qsec, degree = 2), data = mtcars)
mmd = min(mtcars$disp):max(mtcars$disp)
mmq = min(mtcars$qsec):max(mtcars$qsec)

flm = function(x1, x2) ( (ls$coefficients[1]) + (ls$coefficients[2] * x1) +
                           (ls$coefficients[3] * x2) 
                         + (ls$coefficients[4] * x2)
                         ) 

t = outer(X = mmd, Y = mmq, FUN = flm)
persp3D(z = t, ticktype = "detailed")
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, shouldn't `ls$coefficients[4] * x2` be `ls$coefficients[4] * x2 * x2`?

These details could be easily avoided if instead of writing your function to evaluate the fit with new data, you used `predict.lm`. This is what I think the code should look like, making other small improvements I will comment about below:

```
disp.density <- 100L
qsec.density <- 100L
disp.range <- with(mtcars, seq(from       = min(disp),
                               to         = max(disp),
                               length.out = disp.density))
qsec.range <- with(mtcars, seq(from       = min(qsec),
                               to         = max(qsec),
                               length.out = qsec.density))
data.grid <- expand.grid(disp = disp.range,
                         qsec = qsec.range)

fit <- lm(mpg ~ disp + qsec, data = mtcars)
predicted.vec <- predict(ls, data.grid)
predicted.mat <- matrix(predicted.vec, nrow = disp.density,
                                       ncol = qsec.density,
                                   dimnames = list(disp.range,
                                                   qsec.range))
library(???)
persp3D(z = predicted.mat, ticktype = "detailed")
```

And the same code should still work if you replace the formula `mpg ~ disp + qsec` with `mpg ~ disp + poly(qsec, degree = 2)`. Some more notes:

1. It is recommended you avoid variable names like `ls` and `t` since they are very basic functions from R. Or you run the risk of shadowing them.
2. `disp` and `qsec` are not integers so using `min(mtcars$disp):max(mtcars$disp)` is a bit unpredictable. I feel it is better to use `seq` like I did, and with control over the grid density.
3. I was not able to test my code because you did not mention the package name for `persp3D` so it is possible it will need some adjustment. In the future, please make sure to give us everything we need to run your code.